# How to add Object.prototype.x? set to enumerable:false

Tags: javascript, syntax, prototype, enumerable

`$('example')`

console logs `foo {word: "example", letter: function}`

```
                                  ^
```

The log showed me `letter` is a prototype function of foo

```
var foo,$;

(function() {

    foo = $ = function(word) {
        return new foo(word);
    };

    var foo = function(word) {
        //#A
        this.word=word;
        console.log(this.word);
        return this;
    };


    foo.fn = foo.prototype = {

        letter: function(n) {
            console.log(this.word[n]);
            return this;
        }
    };

}());
```

I can't seem to look at `$.fn` or `foo.fn`

```
console.log($.fn);     //fn is undefined
console.log(foo.fn);   //foo is undefined

console.log($.prototype); //shows me constructor and __proto__
```

Why? What if I want add more prototype functions later in the code? Why does it work like a charm with `Array.prototype.something=function...` but, not this code?

I am wondering how this would be done as I said above I can see the `letter` function but if instead of putting the delaration of letter inside the prototype I replace `//A` with

```
Object.defineProperty(this,"letter",{
    value:
        function(n) {
            console.log(this.word[n]);
            return this;
        }
    ,enumerable:false});
```

that hides `letter` from appering Inside the foo object and it leaves the prototype empty. I don't seem to be able to access the prototype object and I don't want to see extra *function junk* appering in console logs If I did add something to it I would see it as junk unless I added it where `//A` is..

But then I am left with something that I can't (understand how to) modify with new methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question doesn't seem to be related to the problem, but here we go:

```
foo = $ = function(word) {
    return new foo(word);
};

var foo = function(word) {
    ...
};
```

is equivalent to

```
var foo;
foo = $ = function(word) {
    return new foo(word);
};

foo = function(word) {
    ...
};
```

I.e. you are creating a local variable `foo` which shadows the outer one. Thus you are never assigning to the global `foo` and never exposing `foo.fn` outside of the function.

You *are* assigning a function to `$`, but you are never assigning `fn` to that function.

---

If I understand correctly what you want to do, then you have to rename the variable so that it doesn't shadow the outer variable, and expose `fn` on the correct function (which will happen automatically if you renamed the variable):

```
var foo,$;

(function() {

    foo = $ = function(word) {
        return new InnerFoo(word);
    };

    var InnerFoo = function(word) {
        //#A
        this.word=word;
        console.log(this.word);
        return this;
    };


    foo.fn = InnerFoo.prototype = {

        letter: function(n) {
            console.log(this.word[n]);
            return this;
        }
    };

}());
```

Comment: This makes sense as to why I'm having trouble accessing its prototype. After youre help I figured out I could then set `Object.defineProperty($.fn,'letter',{enumerable:false})` So I am now closer to my goal +1

Comment: What would be the title you would choose? I am clearly confused. It would not help other users to meet a poorly titled question.